# Laravel 8 Livewire component Undefined variable: header

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have created a Livewire component in **Jetstream** and I have set it as a full-page component in the `web.php` route page as follows:

```
use App\Http\Livewire\PostComponent;
...
Route::get('posts/',PostComponent::class)->name('posts');
```

The `post-component.blade.php` file has originally the following code:

```
<div>
    <h1>If you look to others for fulfillment, you will never truly be fulfilled.</h1>
</div>
```

If I hit the URL `.../posts` I get the following error:

> Undefined variable: header (View:
> /home/vagrant/laravelapp/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

So I have tried adding the slot in the `post-component.blade.php` file:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Dashboard') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    <div>
        <h1>If you look to others for fulfillment, you will never truly be fulfilled.</h1>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Nevertheless, I get that same error.

What am I missing? How do I fix this?

Comment: Check if slot ``header`` exists in the component ``x-app-layout``

Comment: Thanks. I am checking this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1854) link given by M Irfan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is a `Jetstream` project. By default, livewire will use the `app.blade.php` as the layout. And the component will get rendered in the `slot` of the `app.blade.php`.

But since it's a Jetstream project, it has a slot for the header in the layout file.

```html
  <header class="bg-white shadow">
       <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
             {{ $header }}
        </div>
  </header>
```

So to resolve this error, there are two approaches.

1. give the header as the variable for the layout as below in your `PostComponent.php`

```php
 public function render()
 {
        return view('livewire.post-component')
         ->layout('layouts.app', ['header' => 'Post Compoent Page']);
 }
```

2. Create your own layout and only have a slot. (imagine `mylayout.blade.php`)

```html
<head>
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    {{ $slot }}

    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

and use that layout when rendering the livewire component

```php
public function render()
{
   return view('livewire.post-component')->layout('layouts.mylayout');
}
```

There is a `github` [issue](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1854) regarding this topic (a closed one). But keep an eye on it. since `Jetstream` is in it's early stages.

Comment: I forgot to highlight I am using `Jetstream`. You guessed right. Indeed. Thanks for the Github issue link as well.